# Ubuntu 18.04.4LTS won't power back up after suspend

Tags: suspend

My Panasonic Toughbook with Ubuntu 18.04.4LTS 32-bit seems to go into suspend fine, but nothing will wake it back up... never power's back on - everything dark quiet and unresponsive. Have to hold down power button and reboot (not good) :-\

Also, will go thru the motions to hibernate if I use that, but that seems to not work either as powering back on just reboots with all the orphaned error junk scrolling during bootup...

Comment: Waking up from suspend requires all the devices to go from the low-power to the normal state.If sometimes the GPU cannot return to the normal state , it can keep the screen blank. To get started , which GPU do you use ? and which driver version ?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my GPU that actually the kernel or combination of the Driver/Kernel was in charge of that. I had always got trouble when returning from suspend until I used kernel version 5+.

Comment: "which GPU do you use ? and which driver version ?"

I have no idea - how do I find out? BTW - this has been going on since I bought this laptop which started with Ubuntu 16.10...

Comment: "I had always got trouble when returning from suspend until I used kernel version 5+"

I'm using kernel 4.15.0-72 generic - locked it there as every time the update snuck in a new kernel, something got broke ~ things like not shutting down, wifi becoming erratic, etc. With 4.15.0-72 "ALL IS WELL" (except this suspend which has never been able to wake since I got the thing...)